# Detecting data change from Apollo useQuery hook with poll interval

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, apollo-client, react-apollo, use-effect

I have a React app that uses Apollo client to fetch the data from backend using `useQuery()` hook. I want to show a refresh button on screen whenever the data changes in the backend. For that I am using poll interval in the graphql query to fetch data every 5 minutes.

```
const { data, loading, error, refetch, previousData } = useQuery(QUERY, {
            client: apolloClient,
            pollInterval: 300000 // 5 minutes
        });
```

In my react app, I am using useEffect() hook to set the local state to show refreshBanner

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (data?.list !== previousData?.list) {
            setShowRefreshBanner(true);
        }
    }, [data, previousData]);
```

Since the data object would always be recreated it would lead to `useEffect()` running multiple times. Is there a way to detect if the data changed without taking a dependency on data object. Here `data.list` is a list of objects and the change in values are happening inside the objects in the list.